# How to rearrange rows from a data.frame depending to the value of one of the columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, extract

I have a data.frame of about 3000 rows by 7000 columns. The columns contain values collected over time. The first column contains real time values that indicate the real time of the start of the measurements. To illustrate:

```
mat1 <- c(00.00,"f","g","f","g")
mat2 <- c(00.50,"f","g","f","g")
mat3 <- c(00.25,"f","g","f","g")
mat <- as.data.frame(rbind(mat1, mat2, mat3))
colnames(mat) <- c("realtime","datatime1","datatime2","datatime3","datatime4")
mat
```

I want to find the seasonality in the data, and remove it. To do so I need to put the data collected in the same real time in the same column, and fill the beginning and end with zeros or anything else. To illustrate, what I need it something like this:

```
mat1 <- c(00.00,"f","g","f","g",0,0)
mat2 <- c(0,0,00.50,"f","g","f","g")
mat3 <- c(0,00.50,"f","g","f","g",0)
mat <- as.data.frame(rbind(mat1, mat2, mat3))
colnames(mat) <- c("realtime","datatime1","datatime2","datatime3","datatime4")
mat
```

So far I have been trying several things but they all end up requiring manual changes to every row or subset of the data that I extract.
An examples is:

```
mat1 <- c(rep(0,as.numeric(mat[1,1])*4),mat[1,],rep(0,96-(as.numeric(mat[1,1]))*4))
mat2 <- c(rep(0,as.numeric(mat[2,1])*4),mat[2,],rep(0,96-(as.numeric(mat[2,1]))*4))
mat3 <- c(rep(0,as.numeric(mat[3,1])*4),mat[3,],rep(0,96-(as.numeric(mat[3,1]))*4))
rbind(mat1,mat2,mat3)
```

Does anyone know how to do this without all these manual modifications?

Comment: It is not clear what logic is used to get from first version of `mat` to the second version of `mat`. If you can explain it a bit more clearly, perhaps someone can help.

Comment: The logic is in that the values in the column "realtime" (00.00, 00.25 and 00.50 ... up to 23.75 in my full data.frame) indicate the amount of empty cells or 0s that I want before the rows in my new data.frame (multiplied by 4 to avoid 1.75 empty cells). I then also need an inverse amount of empty cells of 0s after my initial row (96-4*"realtime") to make rows of equal size again that fin in a data.frame. So I want something that looks like:

Comment: the second mat that I wrote (I see that I confused you by mistyping 00.50 in row 3 instead of 00.25, which correlated with one 0 in front of the row, and one 0 after the row.